# Extending a class using categories with identical methods name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to extend a class using category **NSArray+Populate.h**:

```
@interface NSArray (Populate)
-(NSArray *) populateArray; 
@end
```

How can I detect the situation if there is another category (from another module or library), extending NSArray with method having the same name ?

For example, if there is a **NSArray+Fill.h**:

```
@interface NSArray (Fill)
-(NSArray *) populateArray; 
@end
```

As I understand, the run-time engine will choose one of the version silently, without any crash ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot detect this situation and you cannot determine which implementation of `-populateArray` takes precedence. Some developers prefer to prefix their category method names for this reason.

Quoting [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html) document,

> A category cannot reliably override methods declared in another category of the same class.
>
> This issue is of particular significance since many of the Cocoa classes are implemented using categories. A framework-defined method you try to override may itself have been implemented in a category, and so which implementation takes precedence is not defined.